# Running SQL INSERT ends up in "Error 1064"

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I wrote this code which is supposed to insert a bunch of values into a database, but whenever i run this code, it says "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"
and "PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near". Can anybody help?

My code, according to those error messages the error is somewhere in the INSERT part:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
  session_start();
}

function getValue1() {
    if (!isset($_GET[r])) {
        return false;
        $referral_code = "-";
    }
    return $_GET[r];
    $referral_code = $_GET[r];
}

// initializing variables
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array(); 

   require("php_db_info.php");

   $dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=user_db;charset=utf8';

       $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username1, $password);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
       $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password_1 = $_POST['password_1'];
  $password_2 = $_POST['password_2'];
  if (getValue('r')) {
    $referral_code = $_GET['r'];
} else {
      $referral_code = "-";
  } 

  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required."); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required."); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required."); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
      array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match.");
  }
  if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/i", $username)) {
    array_push($errors, "You can only use letters, numbers, underscores and dashes.");
  }
  if (strlen($username) <= 1) {
    array_push($errors, "Your username must have at least 2 characters.");
  } 
  if (strlen($username) >= 22) {
  array_push($errors, "Your username must have below 22 characters.");
  } 
  require "server_bannedwords.php";

  $stm_reg1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
  $stm_reg1->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stm_reg1->execute();
  $row = $stm_reg1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if( ! $row) {} else {
    array_push($errors, "Username already exists.");
  }

  $stm_reg2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
  $stm_reg2->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stm_reg2->execute();
  $row = $stm_reg2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if( ! $row) {} else {
    array_push($errors, "Email already exists.");
  }

  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password2 = password_hash($password_1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stm_reg_fin = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, coins, alltimecoins, earnedcoins, referralcoins, vouchercoins, paidout, paypal, bitcoin, referred_by, deleted, date_deleted, verified, date_created, date_active) VALUES (':username', ':email', ':password2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', ':referral_code', '0', NULL, '0', curdate(), curdate()");
     /*   $stm_reg_fin->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm_reg_fin->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm_reg_fin->bindParam(":password2", $password2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm_ref_fin->bindParam(":referral_code", $referral_code, PDO::PARAM_INT);*/
        $stm_reg_fin->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':email' => $_POST['email'], ':password2' => $_POST['password_1'], ':referral_code' => $referral_code));
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $hour = time() + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        setcookie('c_username', $username, $hour);
        setcookie('c_password', $password2, $hour);  
        /* VERIFY OBAVEZNO DODATI ------------------------ */
        header("location: home.php");
  }
} else {
  array_push($errors, "The e-mail does not exist.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your insert query you have miss `)` at end of your query put that like below :

```
 $stm_reg_fin = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, coins,
alltimecoins, earnedcoins, referralcoins, vouchercoins, paidout, paypal, bitcoin,
 referred_by, deleted, date_deleted, verified, date_created, date_active) VALUES
 (':username', ':email', ':password2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '-', 
':referral_code', '0', NULL, '0', curdate(), curdate())"); 
                                                      ^ here
```